# iphone, if possible to select multiple files from Photos gallery via UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible that a user can select multiple images from the photo gallery in iOS using UIImagePickerController? If so, how do I go about achieving it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Not Possible

It is not possible for `UIImagePickerController` to select multiple images at once.

### Reusable Components

However, there are great reusable components that support this. One of examples is [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController). Its screenshot is on [this page](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/elcimagepickercontroller).

Comment: ELCImagePickerController doesn't load the full gallery in iOS 5 and the order of the albums are wrong in versions iOS 5 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to select multiple photos at once. You'll have to let them pick them one by one, I guess.